# How can I select classmates of a given student from a student-class association table?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

If my table looks like the following, how can I select classmates of a given student?

```
student_class_assn
student_id    class_id
1             1
2             1
3             1
4             2
5             2
6             3
```

For example, Student `1` has students `2` and `3` as classmates.

Please help me write a query that pivots on the known `student_id` and selects only the classmates (and not including the given student).

Here is an example using a sub-select. But can you help me write it with joins instead?

```
SET @KNOWN_STUDENT=1;
SELECT
    student_id
FROM
    student_class_assn
WHERE
    class_id IN (
        SELECT class_id FROM student_class_assn WHERE student_id = @KNOWN_STUDENT
    )
    AND student_id != @KNOWN_STUDENT;
```

Given my table above I expect the following results for each given `student_id`:

```
1 returns 2,3
2 returns 1,3
3 returns 1,2
4 returns 5
5 returns 4
6 returns NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is just join the table and pass a conditional

```
SELECT t1.student_id
FROM student_class_assn t
JOIN student_class_assn t1 
    ON t1.class_id = t.student_id 
    AND t1.student_id <> 1
WHERE t.student_id = 1
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51ab6/2)

Answer (score 1):

This will not show students with no classmates:

```
select s1.sid,group_concat(s2.sid order by s2.sid,',')
from
stud_class s1 inner join
stud_class s2 on s1.cid=s2.cid
where s1.sid <> s2.sid
group by s1.sid
order by 1
```